# First Date and Last Date when condition is applied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

| id | start | end | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:18:30.820 | 2021-01-20 08:18:31.740 | Area1 |
| 9 | 22021-01-20 08:18:31.740 | 2021-01-20 08:18:32.643 | Area1 |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:18:32.643 | 2021-01-20 08:18:33.550 | Area1 |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:20:07.290 | 2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 | Area2 |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 | 2021-01-20 08:21:08.190 | Area1 |

I need to create a query with the following output:

| id | start | end | Area |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:18:30.820 | 2021-01-20 08:18:33.550 | Area1 |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:20:07.290 | 2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 | Area2 |
| 9 | 2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 | 2021-01-20 08:21:08.190 | Area1 |

I tried to look after similar situations but I didn't find anything like this.

**@all I can use min and max because I have multiple entries for the same Area. I have corrected the output and input for a better view**

Comment: What's wrong with `MIN` and `MAX`? What *have* you tried? Why didn't it work?

Comment: Group by id and Area and then Min(start) and Max(end)

Comment: You can take a look at here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_min_max.asp

Comment: @ I have edited the main question. Sorry for creating a misunderstanding.

Comment: This is now a gaps and island problem. There are also plenty of example of these on [so].

Comment: @Larnu. Thank you. I will look into it.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this looks like simple aggregation:

```
select id, min(start), max(end), area
from t
group by id, area;
```

Comment: I think the aggregation can be even avoided?

Comment: @Miraziz . . . With a lot of trouble.  Aggregation seems like the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking for something like this

```
drop table if exists #test_table;
go
create table #test_table(
  id        int
 ,[start]   datetime
 ,[end]     datetime
 ,Area      varchar(20));

INSERT INTO #test_table(id, [start], [end], Area) VALUES
(9, '2021-01-20 08:18:30.820', '2021-01-20 08:18:31.740', 'Area1'),
(9, '2021-01-20 08:18:31.740', '2021-01-20 08:18:32.643', 'Area1'),
(9, '2021-01-20 08:18:32.643', '2021-01-20 08:18:33.550', 'Area1'),
(9, '2021-01-20 08:20:07.290', '2021-01-20 08:20:08.190', 'Area2'),
(9, '2021-01-20 08:20:08.190', '2021-01-20 08:21:08.190', 'Area1');

;with 
lag_cte as (
    select *, case when lag(Area) over (partition by id order by [start])<>Area then 1 else 0 end flag
    from #test_table),
grp_cte as (
    select *, sum(flag) over (partition by id order by [start]) grp
    from lag_cte)
select id, min([start]) [start], max([end]) [end], Area
from grp_cte
group by id, Area, grp
order by [start];
```

```
id  start                   end                     Area
9   2021-01-20 08:18:30.820 2021-01-20 08:18:33.550 Area1
9   2021-01-20 08:20:07.290 2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 Area2
9   2021-01-20 08:20:08.190 2021-01-20 08:21:08.190 Area1
```